# Pop view controller after dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have a navigation controller A on which i push the view controller B. From B i present modally the view controller C. I need to dismiss C and pop B at the same time. I would like to that in sequence, keeping the dismiss animation first and then the pop animation from B to A. I tried without success this code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
       [self.presentingViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

Any suggestion on how can i achieve this?

Comment: check if navigation controller is not nil...?

Comment: This log in my button gives "null" `NSLog(@"%@", self.presentingViewController.navigationController);` Can't understand why. I need maybe to create a reference to the view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing in C viewcontoller then :

```
UIViewController *pvc = self.presentingViewController;
UINavigationController *navController = [pvc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] ? (UINavigationController *)pvc : pvc.navigationController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
  [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

or if in B view controller

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

Comment: The button is located in C. I tried your code, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Actually self.presentingViewController returns UINavigationController. See my updated answer.

Comment: @paragShinde any good reason why we are checking this: [pvc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]

Comment: Presenting view controller can be UIViewController or UINavigationViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried popping two times in succession before but not dismissing one and popping another one. You can try what I did and see if it works for you.

In Subview B:

```
- (void)subViewCController:(SubViewCController *)controller didSelectID:(NSNumber *)theID
{
    // do something with theID...
    // for my case, I popped
    // [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // for your case
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // Somehow, adding a small delay works for me and the animation is just nice
    [self performSelector:@selector(backToSubViewA) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];
}

- (void)backToSubViewA
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboards and segues? If so, you can use unwind segue:

In your first view controller (the one you want to jump back *to*, not the one you're returning *from*), create an unwind segue action:

```
- (IBAction)gotoMainMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // if you need to do anything when you return to the main menu, do it here
}
```

Then in storyboard, you can create a segue from the "dismiss" button to the exit outlet icon ([image]) in the bar above the scene, and you'll see `main menu` listed there.

Comment: Sorry, i should have specified, i'm using xib files.

Comment: Understood. I'll keep this answer here in case future readers, who are using storyboards, stumble across this question.